# The Derivative of polynomial function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a generic polynomial function, defined by

$$f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + a_{n - 2}x^{n - 2} + \dots + a_1x + a_0$$

,$n \in \mathbb{N}$

If I define $f(x)$ using sigma notation, so I'll get:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k =0}^{n} a_{n -k}x^{n - k}$$

But I want to calculate the derivative of this function, can i do this?

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{k =0}^{n} a_{n -k}x^{n - k} = \sum_{k =0}^{n}(n - k) a_{n -k}x^{n - k -1}$$

I think this it's just saying that the derivative of a polynomial function i'ts given by the derivatives of the terms of the polynomial. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Easier to define it as $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n{a_kx^k}$$

Comment: Yes, when you have finitely many terms, you can do this easily - simply use the definition of $\displaystyle\sum$. The issue is a bit more complicated, however, as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes, this is fine, but as @Clarinetist says, there is a difficulty as $n\to\infty$. Then, you have to use the limit definition of the derivative and worry about uniform convergence issues. However, for $n$ finite, this definition works, and in fact as the definition used in Abstract Algebra (the so called "formal derivative")

Comment: ok, thanks. ---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the derivative is a linear operation. This means that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have derivatives $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ respectively, then the derivative of the function $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is given by
$$h'(x)\,=\,f'(x)\,+\,g'(x)$$
In words: *`the derivative of a sum is the sum of derivatives`*. Of course, if it's true for the sum of two terms it is true for finite  number of summands. For instance, the derivative of $J(x)=k(x)+l(x)+m(x)$ is $J'(x)=h'(x)+l'(x)+m'(x)$.

That what you call the sigma notation is just a short form for expressing a summation. In this particular case, this summation is finite. Hence the above rule applies and the derivative of that polynomial is simply the sum of derivatives of each term. Explicitly, writing the polynomial as $f(x)=\sum^n_{k=0}a_kx^k$ we have
$$f'(x)\,=\,\sum^n_{k=1}a_k\,k\,x^{k-1}$$.
Notice that the summation index $k$ starts here by $1$: The constant $a_0$ term vanishes when taking the derivate.

Comment: very good explanation, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped. If it helped you might check on accepting the answer and/or up-voting it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to vote up, but I don't have enough reputation... But I could check

Comment: That's fine. You'll get to up-vote soon as well. Thanks.